# Elasticsearch search by substring in array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-plugin

I have the following object in the elastic search and I am trying to find any tags.name that contains a substring. I've tried getting all the tags first and then putting in an aggregate and filter, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong because I'm getting all the tags.names, not the ones that contain that substring.

The object.

```
"hits" : [
      {
          "tags" : [
            {
              "datatype" : "STRING",
              "values" : [
                {
                  "value_concat" : "DOBTEST22",
                  "unit" : "",
                  "value" : "DOBTEST22",
                  "operator" : "",
                  "ordernr" : 0
                }
              ],
              "name" : "hierarchy"
            },
              {
              "datatype" : "STRING",
              "values" : [
                {
                  "value_concat" : "DOBTEST223",
                  "unit" : "",
                  "value" : "DOBTEST223",
                  "operator" : "",
                  "ordernr" : 0
                }
              ],
              "name" : "test24"
            }
          ]
```

This is the query I tried to build and it doesn't work.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "agg": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tags"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "aggregation": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "tags.name",
            "size": 5000,
            "min_doc_count": 0,
            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
            "order": [
              {
                "_count": "desc"
              },
              {
                "_key": "asc"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "filter": {
            "nested": {
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "tags.name": "*hier*"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                  "boost": 1
                }
              },
              "path": "tags",
              "ignore_unmapped": false,
              "score_mode": "sum",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide index mapping ? is your `tags` field is defined as nested ?